# How to get image dimensions from an avif file?

Tags: java, image, heif, avif

I'm looking for a (fast) way to retrieve image metadata from an avif-file in my java-application. This is currently done for many image formats by analyzing the raw header bytes of a file.

I can recognize a file as avif through the magic byte sequence at the beginning of the file: `ftypavif`.
But I'm not able to find any information how to parse the (max) **image width & height** of contained images. For JPEG2000 for example I can search for SIZ marker `0xFF51` and parse dimensions afterwards, but even after spending a lot of time reading through specifications of avif, I'm not able to find something similar for it.

Is my approach incorrect and I can't parse the image dimensions without decoding the image(s)? Or is there any documentation (or even usable library) I missed to retrieve width & height from an avif-file?

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Here is a library implementation, https://github.com/AOMediaCodec/libavif and here is the standard. https://aomediacodec.github.io/av1-avif/#av1-item-configuration-property

Comment: Thanks  for the links, but as stated above I've read through both of it without finding the required Information. Manually including a C-library in my java-application just to get some meta-information doesn't look ideal to me. Any additional hints?

Comment: "but as stated above I've read through both of it " you didn't state that anywhere. The links are the documentation and a library with a reference implementation. I'm sure the information is in there, but I don't know enough about reading the specs to quickly delve into it. Can you link an example image in your post?

Answer (score 7):

Search for [`'ispe'`](https://www.iso.org/standard/66067.html) box (this is a mandatory box/item), skip 4 bytes after the type ([FullBox](https://www.iso.org/standard/83102.html) version and flags) read 4 bytes for image width, read 4 bytes for image height. Profit ;)

[image]

Comment: Remember to link to the relevant spec if you're going to make claims about byte layouts.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ISOBMFF + HEIF. In the first you can find the generic definitions for Box/FullBox in the second the syntax of `ispe` itself.

Comment: I'm sure, but those specs have links, adding links is always good =)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the AVIF files have `ftypavis` (contains animation) and I also saw AVIF with `ftypmif1`

If you want to parse AVIF alone, you need to understand ISOBMFF format and [HEIF container](https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/technical.html) first. There are various properties (like Image spatial Extents (ispe)), then various transformations (crop, rotation, mirror). Images can be stored in a form of image grid...